# Convert Linux drivers to Loadable Kernel Module

Tags: android, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a USB modem driver for linux. Can I convert it to loadable kernel modules? I am thinking of loading it in android kernel and importing to a AMD machine. Please help. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you explain "loading it in android kernel and importing to a AMD machine". I don't understand what you mean. You have the source code for this driver, where would you like it to run? On an Android device or on a x86 desktop?

Comment: I need to run it for android OS. I need to know how to approach this. finally i will run it on a AMD machine. Thanks!!

Comment: when you say "run it for android OS" on which machine will this OS run? will the OS be running on an AMD machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple, you need to cross compile your module if you want to run it in your specific machine-architecture. I mean if you want to load on ARM then you need to cross compile with 
**make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE="toolchain path"**.

Similarly you can do for the rest of the machines.

**NOTE:** If you are compiling on the machine where you need to load then you need not do this. just compile and load with insmod.